# SQL Sort shortest and longest first name by last name

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to sort the first names of my table by their last name and filter out both the shortest and longest first name in two different columns, there are several people with the same last name like Max Bob, Mini Bob, Howard Bob and so on. I only want the shortest and longest first name for the corresponding last name

Example:

| last name | shortest first name | longest first name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mickey | Max | Ronald |
| Duck | Bob | Howard |
| Bob | Max | Howard |

etc.

So far I have:

```
SELECT
COUNT(last_name) as last name,
MIN(first_name) as shortest,
MAX(first_name) as longest
FROM
hr.employees
group by first_name;
```

which gives me the count of the last_name but not the last_name itself

| last name | shortest first name | longest first name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Max | Max |
| 1 | Howard | Howard |
| 2 | Max | Max |
| 2 | Howard | Howard |

but I'm stuck on how to proceed, any advice?

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, we could use the `keep` syntax here:

```
select last_name,
    min(first_name) keep(dense_rank first order by length(first_name)) shortest_last_name,
    min(first_name) keep(dense_rank last  order by length(first_name)) longest_last_name
from employees
group by last_name;
```

If there are ties for the shortest or longest first name, the query picks the "minimum" value, string-wise.

Here is a demo:

```
with employees as (
    select 'Mickey' as last_name, 'Max' as first_name from dual
    union all select 'Mickey', 'Ronald' from dual
    union all select 'Mickey', 'Bill' from dual
    union all select 'Duck', 'Bob' from dual
    union all select 'Duck', 'Howard' from dual
    union all select 'Bob', 'Max' from dual
    union all select 'Bob', 'Howard' from dual
)
select last_name,
    min(first_name) keep(dense_rank first order by length(first_name)) shortest_last_name,
    min(first_name) keep(dense_rank last  order by length(first_name)) longest_last_name
from employees
group by last_name;
```

| LAST_NAME | SHORTEST_LAST_NAME | LONGEST_LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Max | Howard |
| Duck | Bob | Howard |
| Mickey | Max | Ronald |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Okr5oiVq)